# How to add bounces if UICollectionView's content is not enough?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

If `UITableView's` content is not enough, the bounces is still enabled.

However, if `UICollectionView's` content is not enough, the bounces is disabled.

How to add bounces ? And how to change the size of bounces ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955807/enable-bounce-scroll-for-uicollectionview-while-no-cells

Comment: UICollectionView has the properties alwaysBounceHorizontal and alwaysBounceVertical. Setting the horizontal to YES did the trick.